# please what is node.js eqivalent of this python code

Tags: python, node.js

What is node.js code equivalent of this python code?

```
python -c 'import pty;
pty.spawn("/bin/sh")'
```

I am trying to get a linux shell and I have tried the code below:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('/bin/bash', function (error, stdOut, stdErr) {console.log(stdOut);});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You would get more help from node.js people if you described what you're trying to accomplish rather than the python equivalent.  The way you've asked your question, it can only really be answered by someone who knows both Python and node.js pretty well.  If you just describe the problem you're trying to solve, it can be answered by anyone who knows node.js.

Comment: thanks jfriend00, what i am looking for is to be able to run system(linux) level command on node interactive mode and or get linus shell

Answer (score 0):

`child_process` module also contains **spawn** method. You can try it, it's more flexible than **exec**.